# I get an error compiling my Angular app: Property 'arrayRemove' does not exist on type 'typeof FieldValue'

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an Angular app that uses Firebase.

One of the functions is this:

```
borrarAnimal(path:string, id:string, animal:Animal[]){
    const collection = this.angularFirestore.collection(path);
    return collection.doc(id).update({
      'animals': firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(animal)})
    }
```

It's used to remove an array from a field. I get an error while compiling that says:

> Error: src/app/services/firestore.service.ts:57:29 - error TS2339: Property 'arrayRemove' does not exist on type 'typeof FieldValue'.

My imports are:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { FieldValue } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { Animal, Batuda } from '../interfaces/batuda.interface';
import { Usuari } from '../interfaces/user';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

I need to know where is the error to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you shared, since you import with:

```
import { FieldValue } from 'firebase/firestore';
```

The `arrayRemove` should be:

```
collection.doc(id).update({
  'animals': FieldValue.arrayRemove(animal)})
}
```

---

If this doesn't work (it looks a bit odd for the v9 or later SDK), have a look at the example in the Firebase documentation on [adding items to and removing items from an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_11) in the modular v9 syntax:

```
import { doc, updateDoc, arrayUnion, arrayRemove } from "firebase/firestore";

const washingtonRef = doc(db, "cities", "DC");

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
await updateDoc(washingtonRef, {
    regions: arrayUnion("greater_virginia")
});

// Atomically remove a region from the "regions" array field.
await updateDoc(washingtonRef, {
    regions: arrayRemove("east_coast")
});
```

So here `arrayRemove` is a top-level function that you need to import separately.